# How to count duplicate elements in array C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have an array of numbers. **I need to find out what numbers are repeated and count the number of repetitions**.

I'm thinking of doing this through 2 arrays:

In the first, I will write the number and in the second the number of repetitions of the element. But for this, each number will have to be constantly compared with the first array of numbers.

Do you have any ideas on how to make a faster algorithm?

Examples:

Array of numbers:

```
1 9 7 8 9 6 9 8 7 1
```

Two arrays that will come out as a result (if you know how to do it with one array, it will be cool):

1 array:

```
1 9 7 8 6
```

2 array:

```
2 3 2 2 1
```

Comment: Use `std::unordered_map<int, int>`?

Comment: Use a map to calculate the occurrences of these array elements.

Comment: map is very slow, I need something faster

Comment: If array elements are in a range 0 <= x <=10^5, you can create an array and update there index values to calculate occurrences of these array elements.

Comment: @Rozer -- "map is very slow" compared to what? If the goal is simply to count duplicates among 10 elements, sure, a map will be much slower than brute force. But how large is the actual problem that you have to solve?

Comment: Sort the array. After that, counting duplicates is trivial.

Comment: @Pete Becker the program can process very huge data. Is it better to use map for huge volume? Now I have it implemented through 2 arrays.

Comment: What is the expected range of values and what is the expected number of unique values?

Comment: Range of values: all numbers that are in int, unsigned. Few numbers will be unique. Basically, numbers will repeat.

Comment: If the numbers are "_any `unsigned int`_" and not just single digits as in the examples, or a small finite range,  and the array can be "huge", then any map would be huge too and also non-deterministic.  If the order of the array is not important, sort in place, so no additional memory is required.  If not,  sort a copy - you already proposed a second array in any case, but you don't know in advance how big that will be, so the memory management for that is likely to be more work and time than a sort.

Comment: @Rozer In CS theory, sorting an array is O(N*log(N)), building a hash map is O(N). In reality, arrays are in continuous memory addresses so sorting them is rather fast, while each insertion into a hash map calls `malloc()` which is rather slow. It’s often faster to `std::sort` despite the CS theory says otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

All Unordered_set operations are O(1) and O(n) in worse case, but usually remain constant (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/unordered_set-in-cpp-stl/).
In your case you are iterating twice your array, so it would be O(n2). In this case you iterate your array once O(n) and use O(1) set operations, so it would be a faster solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int arr[10] = {1, 9, 7, 8, 9, 6, 9, 8, 7, 1};
    unordered_set<int> numbersSet;
    unordered_set<int> duplicateSet;
    int duplicatesCount = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        int number = arr[i];
        numbersSet.insert(number);
        if (numbersSet.find(number) != numbersSet.end())
        {
            duplicatesCount++;
            duplicateSet.insert(number);
        }
    }

    cout << "\nAll elements duplicated : ";
    unordered_set<int>::iterator itr;
    for (itr = duplicateSet.begin(); itr != duplicateSet.end(); itr++)
        cout << (*itr) << endl;

    return 0;
}

All elements duplicated : 6
8
7
9
1
```

Comment: This doesn't really address the question. O(whatever) is about how the speed **scales** when the problem size is increased. It doesn't tell you anything about which approach is faster for a particular set of data. For small data sets, the overhead of a map (in whatever form) can kill performance.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
    const int SIZE = 10;
    int arr[SIZE] = {1, 9, 7, 8, 9, 6, 9, 8, 7, 1};
    int find[SIZE] = {0};
    int repeat[SIZE] = {0};
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        temp = arr[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
        {
            if (i == j)
                continue;
            else{
                if (temp == arr[j])
                {
                    find[i] = temp;
                    repeat[j]++;
                }   
            }
        }       
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << ' ';
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        cout << find[i] << ' ';
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        cout << repeat[i] + 1 << ' ';
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).